# How to create ConsumerTemplate in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp

I have camel processor which reads a file from directory using ConsumerTemplate as shown below

```
@Component
public class FileReaderProcessor implements Processor {

    @Consume
    private ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        final byte[] filecontent = consumerTemplate.receiveBody(SOURCE_FILE_COMPONENT,
                byte[].class);

    }
}
```

However when i tried below code it works

```
final byte[] filecontent = exchange.getContext().createConsumerTemplate().receiveBody(SOURCE_FILE_COMPONENT,
                byte[].class);
```

The problem is i need to annotate the ConsumerTemplate and use it my code. kindly help me to use ConsumerTemplate with annotation

```
@Consume
    private ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate;
```

Comment: Since its a spring annotated class with `@Component` then you ought to be able to use spring's `@Autowired` etc.

Comment: something like this                                                                       
    @Autowired                                                                                      
    private ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate;

Answer (score 0):

If you check ConsumerTemplate class you will notice that it extends Service. That means it can be Autowired as any other component in Spring Boot, which I am guessing you are using based on @Component annotation used in your code. So the solution is pretty simple:

```
@Autowired
private ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate;
```